# How can I get 2 attributes and I apply a function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get 2 attributes with jQuery and change a value in it depending on the state of the application.

```
$(this).attr('id', function (i, val) {
   return val.replace('More', 'Less');
});
```

That code above works perfect, it does what I need. 
But I need something like this:

```
$(this).attr('id, theOtherAttr', function (i, val) {
   return val.replace('More', 'Less');
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station" theOtherAttr="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station"></a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you descrive what exactly you need?

Comment: Just call it twice with the different attribute in the second one.

Comment: Can you declare the function and then chain the commands? `function myFunc(i, val) {} ; $(this).attr('id, myFunc).attr('theOtherAttr', myFunc)`

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this code, because something like this should work:

```
$(this).attr('id', myFunc).attr('theOtherAttr', myfunc)
```

by using a extra function:

```
function myfunc(parameter1, parameter2) {
   // do stuff
} ;
```

---

**note**: You can always add multiple attributes using the `.attr()` method:

```
.attr({
    parameter1:"...", 
    parameter2:"..."
});
```

So in your case something like this will be the right approach:

```
$("*").attr('id', function(i, value) {
  var attribute1 = value
  var attribute2 = $(this).attr('secondattribute'); 

  return ""
});
```

Comment: What can I do in the return? I mean, I can not have 2 returns. For the `id` and the `theOtherAttr` attrs I need to replace the word More for Less.

Answer (score 1):

You can set and get the second attribute inside the function using `$(this)` selector.

```js
$("a").attr('id', function(i, val) {
  console.log(val); //First attribute

  let attr2 = $(this).attr('theOtherAttr'); //Getting the 2nd attr
  console.log(attr2);

  //Do your process with val and attr2

  //Return to change the `id` attr
  return val.replace('More', 'Less');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station" theOtherAttr="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station_theOtherAttr"></a>
```

If 2 attributes are the same, you can just

```js
$("a").attr("id", function(i, val) {

  //Set both
  $(this).attr({
    id: val.replace('More', 'Less'),
    theOtherAttr: val.replace('More', 'Less')
  });

  console.log( "id - ", $(this).attr("id") );
  console.log( "theOtherAttr - ", $(this).attr("theOtherAttr") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station" theOtherAttr="BAMS_Q1_See_More_Clover_Station"></a>
```

Comment: If you look closer, the attr `theOtherAttr` has the same value of `id`, I need to replace in both of them the word More for Less